# What is the purpose of calling gl.enableVertexAttribArray(); function in WebGL

Tags: graphics, webgl

In WebGL before we call the `drawArrays()` function we call this function called `enableVertexAttribArray()` passing the reference to a variable in my compiled glsl program which stores the vertex positions of the object we are going to draw. Can someone explain to me what it does and why we have to call that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes in a vertex shader are disabled by default. To use one, you have to first enable it with this function.

You still need to bound a buffer to an enabled attribute, the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#6.5) says this:

> If a vertex attribute is enabled as an array via enableVertexAttribArray but no buffer is bound to that attribute via bindBuffer and vertexAttribPointer, then calls to drawArrays or drawElements will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error.